# How to have two navbars, one only 50% width and centered?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I created a page with **bootstrap 2.3.2** with 2 navbars.

navbar 1 is in original bootstrap-style and full-width --> no problem.

#### navbar 2 is

1. custom style --> solved.
2. about 50% of the width and centered

#### Problem:

Can't get the width to 50% and can't get it centered.

I tried adding `span6 offset3` to the `<div class="navbar">` --> still full width. Adding the classes to the parent-div made no difference either.

#### This is my simplified HTML:

```
<h3>two navbars, different styles</h3>

<!-- navbar one: full width -->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- navbar two: custom styling, 50% width, centered -->
<div class="container navbartwo">
    <div class="span6 offset3 navbar"> <!-- Problem here -->
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michi001/byk64qr3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right, but `container` class adds margin, so:

**CSS**

```
.navbar-snd {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>two navbars, different styles</h3>

<!-- navbar one: full width -->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- navbar two: custom styling, 50% width, centered -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-snd"> <!-- Problem here -->
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***Update***:
Here's a fiddle (from the last version): http://jsfiddle.net/byk64qr3/5/

Comment: wow, that's simple :-) no need for bootstrap here. Can it be done though with bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.X is a requirement or you could use newer versions?

Comment: 2.3.2 is required, because it is part of Joomla 3.x

Comment: offset3 is a fixed margin-left, so you could override .span6.navbar with float: none and set margin to zero. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/byk64qr3/7/

Comment: can't see any effect in the fiddle? anyway, your solution is good, no need for extra tweaks.